# Installing SharePoint Server 2010 on Windows 7 x64

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, windows-7

I'm trying to install SharePoint Server 2010 on my Windows 7 x64 environment for development.  I'm using the RTM .iso from MSDN.   When I try to install, I get an error that my environment isn't supported and that I need to install it on Windows Server 2008.  It was my understanding (from many sources, including Microsoft), that SharePoint 2010 would support installation on Windows 7.  Has this support been dropped?  Are there installation instructions for installing on Windows 7 in a way other that what is expected?

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed [these installation steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx)?

Specifically:

> open the installation configuration file, config.xml, located in the following path: c:\SharePointFiles\files\Setup\config.xml
>
> Add this line inside the  tag:
>
> `<Setting Id="AllowWindowsClientInstall" Value="True"/>`
>
> ◦Microsoft FilterPack 2.0 Beta. At a command prompt, type the following:
>
> c:\SharePointFiles\PrerequisiteInstallerFiles\FilterPack\FilterPack.msi

Comment: +1, By default it doesn't allow installation on Win7 to insure only those who actually read the documentation can install it. Also, it is not *supported* on Win7, it's just *allowed* for development purposes.

Comment: Yea, those are the instructions I'm following.  The extraction piece just isn't working, so I can't get to the config file.  It worked when I installed it on 7 in beta, but this is a different 7 machine.  Maybe it's an extraction problem.