# Cannot install Sharepoint Foundation in windows 7 Home 64 bits

Tags: sharepoint

Why can't I install on  windows 7 Home 64 bits 4 Go ? Anyone tried ?

Comment: Here's at lest one other person with similar difficulties - http://serverfault.com/questions/160316/160322#160322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this Technet article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx) which seems to detail what you need to do.

Having quickly glanced at it, it looks like setup does an Operating System check and if you have not specifically edited a configuration file, it won't allow installation on a non-server version of Windows.